# Cannot connect to Openfire server on Azure

Tags: azure, xmpp, openfire

I have an OpenFire server running on an Azure VM but I cannot connect to it externally. I have opened the 5222/5223 endpoints on the VM portal and even turned the firewall off on the VM itself.

If I install Spark on the VM I can connect but not externally.

Comment: Did you check the domain name / IP you are using to connect from you client ? You should be using the Azure DNS name as server IP or even better setup XMPP DNS for your domain with SRV records.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond I am doing exactly that. The odd thing is that I can access the admin console externally from a browser with the name and port 9090 but no client can connect to the server

Comment: Can you telnet on port 5222 with that name from your external machine ? If yes, that means that the way the client is configured does not route the traffic to the right server.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond I can telnet on port 9090 but not 5222.

Comment: Possible error is that it openfire is only on localhost but not on public interface.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond but then how would I be able to access the Admin Console on port 9090

Comment: That's another port, so bind interface can be different.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond so how can I go about checking port 5222?

Comment: You can try telnet on localhost ip and on public IP to compare. If it works the same, it listen on all interfaces.